# can somebody help me? My VS code does not open, it just stays in "Setting up your codespace"

Tags: visual-studio-code

my probles is that the VS code just stays loading, it just stays like this.[Then, after like 30 minutes, it says "codespace is stopped"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnuMP.png)   [codespace is stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQtXR.png)